# Python : How to get sum of all values until a specific key is reached in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python and have a doubt regarding dictionary operations.

I am maintaining a dictionary as follows -

```
 dict = {counter:distance}.
```

**For example -**

```
 dict = {1:1, 2:10, 3:27, 4:10, 5:7, 6:10}
```

For a given key, I wish to find the total distance to reach that key.

For given key=5, total distance returned should be `(1+10+27+10) = 48.`

I came up with a simple solution as follows -

```
input_key = raw_input()
dist = 0
for key,value in dict:
if key == input_key
    break
else
    dist += value
return dist
```

I am looking for some in built function or library that I can use to achieve this.

My requirement is that I am writing data to an output file.
The format is as follows - docid \t termid \t number
100\t2943\t3

I have for loops which run on each docid and termid.
Termid can be repeated in the loop in which case I need to modify the line in output file. Hence, if docid 100 and termid 2943 is encoutered again with number as 58, then above line needs to be changed to - 
100\t2943\t3\t58

In this way same line in output file can be modified multiple times based on docid and termid.

I am looking to reduce time spent in searching the '^docid\ttermid' pattern in output file and then modifying the line. Hence I plan to maintain a dictionary which should maintain offset in output file.
This way I can loop over the dictionary and get offset in file, read line and modify the same.

Comment: You're relying on order in a dictionary.

Comment: Why is this a dict, anyway? If the `counter` values always increase by 1 every time, you should be using a list.

Comment: Are there a lot of missing counters? Otherwise you should consider using a `list`

Comment: The key in dictionary can be something else as well like a string.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary is not an ordered mapping. You need to use other sequence data structure, or [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want mapping.

And, iterating over dictionary does not yields key-value pairs, but keys.

Here's a solution that use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> d = OrderedDict([(1,1), (2,10), (3,27), (4,10), (5,7), (6,10)])
>>> print sum(map(d.get, itertools.takewhile(lambda key: key != 5, d)))
48
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do cannot be done with [**dict**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and get repeatable answers. Python dictionaries are unordered. You will get arbitrary answers across Python implementations.

Depending on the version of Python you are using, you may be able to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: I disagree. I explicitly answered his question, explained why he cannot do what he is trying to do, then offered a hint on how to proceed. The OP can then re-implement and come back if he runs into a problem. I think that approach leads to better muscle memory for learning. If I gave an explicitly implementation they would just copy/paste/forget.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
input_key = int(raw_input())

dist = sum(dict[i] for i in xrange(1, input_key))
```

For example:

```
>>> dict = {1:1, 2:10, 3:27, 4:10, 5:7, 6:10}
>>> sum(dict[i] for i in xrange(1, 5))
48
```

Note that the code you have given will not work consistently, as the key ordering is undefined in a dictionary object; the key-value pairs could iterate in *any* order.  The code in this answer will instead iterate through the numbers 1 to `input_key` - 1, summing the values stored in the dictionary at those keys.

Answer (score 0):

The first you need to do is to order the dict you can do this with [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Here is an example:

```
import collections
input_key = int(raw_input()) # In this example I suppose is 5
dict = {1:1, 2:10, 3:27, 4:10, 5:7, 6:10}
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))
In: sum(od[m] for m in filter(lambda x: x<input_key, od))
Out: 48
```

Comment: This answer, while equivalent to the code in the original question, also relies on dictionary key ordering, which is undefined.  Mutating the dictionary can cause the keys to iterate in a completely different order, producing a different result.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = {1:1, 2:10, 3:27, 4:10, 5:7, 6:10}
>>> sum((x[1] for x in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0)) if x[0] < 5))
48
```

**Notes:**

- `dict`(s) are not an ordered data structure.
- `sorted` and `.items()` are used to give us an ordered sequence of `(count, distance)`
- This is a generator expression which finally get consumed using `sum()`.
- It would be better to use a `list` of `tuple`(s) here. e.g: `[(1, 1), (2, 10), ...]`

*As a function:*

```
def distance(d, k):
    return sum((x[1] for x in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0)) if x[0] < k))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are missing keys in your data structure, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (else, use a list, as others have already suggested).

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict({ ... }, lambda: 0)

def dist_until(i, data):
    return sum(data[j] for j in range(1, i))
```

Also, avoid naming your variable `dict`.